# Why my awk string match not working?

Tags: unix, awk

```
$ echo foooobazbarrrrr |
> gawk 'match($0, /(fo+).+(bar*)/, arr)
>         {print arr[1], arr[2] }'
```

The output of this code should be `foooo barrrr` but on my Ubuntu, it is not working and failed.

If I wrote this code

```
> gawk 'match($0, /(fo+).+(bar*)/)
>         {print }'
```

Then its working. Why is the first version not working?

Comment: This (your first try) is straight from the gawk's user's guide and works just fine.

Comment: I've edited your post to try to show you actually typed into your terminal. Please edit your question to show what the awk command printed on each attempt.

Comment: When I ran the command on my Ubuntu server, it printed `foooo barrrr` as expected. I suspect your problem is due to the extra line break added to the middle of the awk command.

Comment: due to confusion with your prompt PS2 presence in line, it's hard to find the problem (code was coming from [gawk manual](https://www.gnu.org/software/gawk/manual/html_node/String-Functions.html) i presume

Answer (score 1):

Your command is slightly different from the example in the [GNU manual](https://www.gnu.org/software/gawk/manual/html_node/String-Functions.html#index-differences-in-awk-and-gawk_002c-match_0028_0029-function). It has the opening `{` at the very start so that there's no pattern to match and the newline is required to separate the two awk commmands.

```
$ echo foooobazbarrrrr | gawk '{ match($0, /(fo+).+(bar*)/, arr)
> print arr[1], arr[2] }'
foooo barrrrr
```

Alternatively, you could use a semi-colon instead of a newline to separate the commands:

```
$ echo foooobazbarrrrr | gawk '{ match($0, /(fo+).+(bar*)/, arr); print arr[1], arr[2] }'
foooo barrrrr
```

Your version of the command will work if it’s entered as one line:

```
$ echo foooobazbarrrrr | gawk 'match($0, /(fo+).+(bar*)/, arr) {print arr[1], arr[2] }'
foooo barrrrr
```